# Do you need to zeropad an image of 1920*1080 to 2048*2048 when using the Cooley-Tukey FFT?

Tags: fourier-analysis

User @Paul_R wrote that you need to zeropad an image of 1920*1080 = **2^20,984**

to 2048*2048 = **2^22** when using the Cooley-Tukey FFT?

Why don't we just zeropad it to **2^21**=2048*1024?

Comment: If you're using FFTW anyway, you really don't need to pad; the software is smart enough to perform a prime factor FFT.

Comment: @J.M. Can you answer my question about the FFTW? http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9395/does-the-fftw-have-a-cost-of-knlog-2n

Comment: Sorry, no account there. But, as noted in the implementation notes for FFTW, the prime factor algorithms are asymptotically $n\log\,n$, with the difficulty in the factorization of your array's dimensions.

Comment: I think that this question (or a closely related one) has been asked and answered on at least three different SE sites: math, [dsp](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/9406/235) and [cs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12430/2017).

Answer (score 1):

Because changing $1080$ to $1024$ is *truncating* your data, throwing away 56 of the columns.

Comment: Why can't we move those 56 columns? So it will fit inside? 2^21 pixels?

Comment: You can rearrange the data any way you like; but then you'd be doing an FFT on the rearranged data rather than the data you actually care about.

Comment: Someone wrote "The algorithm that Cooley and Tukey presented in their classic paper (Math. Comp. 19 (1965), 297-301. http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1965-0178586-1) can be applied to any composite length. The performance advantages are greatest for highly composite lengths, of which powers-of-2 are one example, and lengths of powers-of-2 result in other advantages on binary computers, so it has become a common misconception that the algorithm is only applicable to signals whose length is a power of 2." Does that mean we don't need any zeropadding at all?

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation for FFTW to see what expects as input.

Comment: Why the FFTW? I was talking about the Cooley-Tukey FFT